# New to cesium js and whenever I run the command npm run server is leading to issues

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I started this internship and I was assigned this webGIS project and this is my first working with CesiumJs. They gave me samples code and I am trying run the command 'npm run server' but it's showing this particular error with the _Hash function.

```
node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at module.exports (\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat\webapps\3D\code2\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)   
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat\webapps\3D\code2\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat\webapps\3D\code2\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)    
    at \Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat\webapps\3D\code2\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at \Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat\webapps\3D\code2\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at \Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat\webapps\3D\code2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat\webapps\3D\code2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat\webapps\3D\code2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat\webapps\3D\code2\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at \Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat\webapps\3D\code2\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9       
    at \Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat\webapps\3D\code2\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:90:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v19.7.0
```

This is the problem that I am getting.

I tried solving the dependency issues with various dependencies that they had installed. I would like get a  detailed solution because it's a completely new domain for me.